# Is there a way to estimate the energy of desorption of an adsorbed molecule?

Tags: physical-properties-of-materials, binding-energy, adsorption

I'm studying the adsorption of several molecules in metal organic frameworks (MOFs) using both experimental and computational methods. Experimetally I can easily obtain the temperature at which a molecule is adsorbed from the material. But I was wondering if there is a way to get the same information computationally.

Someone asked something similar [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/converting-adsorption-binding-energy-to-absolute-temperature?noredirect=1#comment20084_1004), but to my understanding the OP did not got a satisfatory answer, or at least did not pursue the topic. I do have interaction energy calculated, i.e. $$E_\text{Int}= E_\text{MOF+Ads} - (E_\text{MOF} + E_\text{Ads})$$

Comment: Do you want to estimate the desorption energy or the desorption temperature, or both? Note also that the latter is not completely well-defined, since it depends on the temperature ramp rate (not sure if this is the correct technical term, but you get my idea)

Comment: Are you trying to computationally predict an isobar/isotherm? Even if the binding energy or enthalpy is held constant there will be a variable amount of the small molecule adsorbed as you change the temperature or pressure (a simple example would be with the Langmuir isotherm). You can use DFT computed energies as parameters for a Langmuir model to try to predict the uptake of your small molecule in the MOF. Another approach is to use GCMC.

Comment: @wzkchem5 both. Yes it is true that the ramp would affect that slightly, but I have desorption on several materials, using the same ramp, and they desorb at really different temperatures. I'm not really concerned with the absolute value but to show computationally that there is a similar trend from computational calculations.

Comment: @AGS I can easily control the amount of probe per unit cell experimentally. The material is saturated and then excess (weakly bound) molecules are removed. With that said I think both the Langmuir model and GCMC would be to compute the fully saturated material right?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the temperature swing needed to go from a fully bound to fully unbound material?

Comment: @AGS I'm not sure what you mean by temperature swing, essentially I'm trying to compare the temperature needed to remove a molecule interacting with a specific site, experimentally I get that from a temperature programmed desorption (TPD)

Comment: I’m referring to lowering the temperature to bind the molecules and then raising it to unbind the molecules (temperature swing adsorption). My point is that there’s no one temperature at which a molecule unbinds. When you have a whole bunch of binding sites, you find that the number of adsorbed molecules is a function of the temperature. A Langmuir isotherm or isobar is one model you could use and parameterize it with DFT energies, and you’ll be able to get a function which gives the amount of molecules adsorbed at each temperature.

Comment: For example, at very low temperatures you should find that almost all of the sites are occupied, and as you raise the temperature, some molecules will be adsorbed. In this sense, it’s unclear what it means to calculate the temperature at which the molecule desorbs since you get some number of molecules desorbing at all temperatures.

Comment: @AGS but when we have a molecule that is interacting/bonding there is a minimum energy required to break that interaction/bond and release the molecule

Comment: You would get at that with the binding energy or enthalpy, and the rate would depend on the barrier height which can be calculated with transition state methods. 

If you want to compare why different materials have different adsorption behaviors, the first thing to compare would be the binding energy.

Comment: You could estimate that for kT ~ the binding energy the molecule might desorb, but my earlier point was that in simple models like Langmuir adsorption you have some molecules desorb below this temperature and some stay adsorbed above this temperature, so if you’re talking about the system as a whole I’m not sure if it makes sense to calculate “the temperature needed to remove a molecule.”

Comment: @manuelpb were these comments helpful? Did you get an answer? Please update us! We'll close your question for now since you haven't signed in for about 2 months, but we can re-open the question whenever you return (just leave a comment here) :)